# Circle on taxicab metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, proof-explanation

The taxicab metric of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is deﬁned by d($\vec{v}$,$\vec{u}$)= $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n$$|v_i−u_i|$. Show
that the taxicab metric does satisfy all of the properties of a distance function. What is a circle in the taxicab metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$? Why is it called the taxicab metric?
Note that the taxicab metric is actually the distance function deﬁned by the p- norm deﬁned above but with p=1.

Comment: Your last sentence is irrelevant, right? You haven't included the definition of the p-norm, so including this sentence only confuses.

Comment: Correct; just for your mathematical enlightenment.

Comment: ok. Have you tried some particular cases? What's the taxicab distance between $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$? between $(0,0)$ and $(1,2)$? What does the open "ball" of "radius" $1$ around $(0,0)$ look like?

Comment: btw 0,0 and 1,1 it's 2 and btw 0,0 and 1,2 it's obviously 3, for open circle it would be 1. What about R^2 though? -- I get it will be the radius, but what about the name "taxicab"?

Comment: Think about a city where the streets are numbered and run east-west and the avenues are numbered and run north-south. How far is it from 4th street and fifth avenue to ninth street and 10th avenue? How about in your metric? How far is it from (4,5) to (9,10)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a vector $x\in\mathbb R^n$, define
$$\|x\|_1:=\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|.$$
We want to show that this is a norm. Positive-definiteness is clear from the observation that the the sum of nonnegative numbers is nonnegative, and equal to zero iff each number is zero. If $a\in\mathbb R$ then 
$$\|ax\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n |ax_i| =|a|\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|, $$
establishing homogeneity. Finally, if $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$ then
$$\|x+y\|_1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_i+y_i|\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| + \sum_{i=1}^n |y_i|, $$
which follows from the triangle inequality on real numbers.

The norm $\|\cdot\|_1$ then defines a metric on $\mathbb R^n$ by
$$d_1(x,y) = \|x-y\|_1. $$
It is clear from inspection that $d_1(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$ and from symmetry that $d_1(x,y)=d_1(y,x)$. It remains to verify the triangle inequality; if $x,y,z\in\mathbb R^n$ then
\begin{align}
d_1(x,z) &= \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-z_i| \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-y_i+y_i-z_i|\\
&\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-y_i| + \sum_{i=1}^n |y_i-z_i|\\
&= d_1(x,y) + d_1(y,z).
\end{align}

A "circle" in the $l^1$ metric with center $p$ and radius $r$ is the set
$$\{x\in\mathbb R^n : d_1(x,p) = r\}.$$

I will leave it to you to figure out what that looks like (in two dimensions, that is!).